# Trying to forward SMTP port on strongswan IPsec tunneled docker container?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, ipsec

I have successfully setup a vpn tunnel with `strongswan` within a docker container and want to use that tunneled connection to forward specific ports like SMTP to a host on the other side of the tunnel, in my case `host 10.0.0.10`.

The goal would be to be able to use SMTP in my app directly by connecting to `strongswan-container` service in the middle like this

```
(smtp-host)-[IPSec-tunnel]-(strongswan-container [exposes port 25 and forwards everything to tunneled smtp-host])-[some-docker-network]-(my-mail-sending-app-container [calls strongswan-container:25 for smtp])
```

after reading some docs about this I tried these `iptables` commands on the `strongswan-container` but with no success:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.10:25
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.0.10 --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
```

on the `my-mail-sending-app-container` I tried running

```
telnet strongswan-container 25
```

but it would simply wait for a response until timeout.

What is the problem with my `iptables` command?

`iptables-save` output after strongswan has connected to the tunnel:

```
root@14d43f1e2f55:/# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Thu Jul 22 16:25:04 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:112]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:112]
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/16 -d 192.168.112.2/32 -i eth0 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.112.2/32 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul 22 16:25:04 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Thu Jul 22 16:25:04 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:1600]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:1600]
:DOCKER_OUTPUT - [0:0]
:DOCKER_POSTROUTING - [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11/32 -j DOCKER_OUTPUT
-A POSTROUTING -d 127.0.0.11/32 -j DOCKER_POSTROUTING
-A DOCKER_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.11:46701
-A DOCKER_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.11:58024
-A DOCKER_POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.11/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 46701 -j SNAT --to-source :53
-A DOCKER_POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.11/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 58024 -j SNAT --to-source :53
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul 22 16:25:04 2021
```

my `ipsec.conf`:

```
config setup
     strictcrlpolicy=no
     uniqueids=no

# left is local by default, left and right otherwise dynamically detected
conn %default

conn "ezvpn"
    keyexchange=ikev2
    aggressive=yes
    ike=(some-ciphers)     # Phase1 parameters
    esp=(some-ciphers)              # Phase2 parameters
    left=192.168.112.2         # local IP used to connect to IOS
    leftid=12.123.123.1                 # IKEID (group name) used for IOS
    leftfirewall=yes
    leftauth=psk
    rightauth=psk
    fragmentation=yes
    right=12.123.123.2        #gateway (IOS) IP
    rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/16
    rightfirewall=yes
    auto=route
    type=tunnel
    ikelifetime=180m
    keylife=60m
```

Comment: Can you actually reach the SMTP host (`10.0.0.10`) from the strongSwan container? Does the container expose port 25 (via `EXPOSE` or `--expose`) or maybe even publish it?

Comment: @ecdsa yes to both, issue is not docker related, just mentioned it because of the extra iptables settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing `traefik` into my `strongswan` container and then using the `TCP routing` capabilities of `traefik` to expose the tunneled port internally.

`Dockerfile` (I am fully aware that this can be achieved using `alpine` as well):

```
FROM ubuntu


RUN apt update && apt-get install -yf wget iputils-ping telnet strongswan iptables \
    && ln -sf /conf/ipsec.conf /etc/ipsec.conf \
    && ln -sf /conf/ipsec.secrets /etc/ipsec.secrets \
    && echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf \
    && wget -O /traefik.tar.gz https://github.com/traefik/traefik/releases/download/v2.4.12/traefik_v2.4.12_linux_amd64.tar.gz \
    && tar -zxvf /traefik.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /traefik /usr/bin/traefik


COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY /strongswan /conf
COPY /traefik-conf /traefik-conf

CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

{
    # wait to make sure ipsec is started when upping the tunnel
    sleep 2
    ipsec up ezvpn
    traefik --configfile /traefik-conf/traefik.yml
} &

exec ipsec start --nofork "$@"
```

`traefik-conf/traefik.yml`:

```
# https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/
entryPoints:
  smtp:
    address: ":1025" # the port that listens within the docker network

accessLog: {}

providers:
  file:
    directory: /traefik-conf/dynamic/
    # I use dynamic configurations for local development
    watch: true

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
```

`/traefik-conf/dynamic/dynamic.yml`:

```
tcp:
  # https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule_1
  routers:
    smtp-router:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - smtp
      service: smtp-service

  # https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#services
  services:
    smtp-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - address: 10.0.0.1:25 # replace with your target IP & service port
```

See [here](https://github.com/tgerakitis/docker-ipsec-tunnel) for the full example.

Comment: I have the same issue but this wouldn't work for UDP

Comment: @fjch1997 you need to take a look at the traefik documentation. My example shows TCP only but it can also be adjusted for UDP .